# Execute cucumber scenarios containing given step

Tags: cucumber, scenarios

I modified a step definition. How do I tell cucumber to run all but only those scenarios containing this step?

Answer (score 0):

Put a tag on the relevant scenario(s) like this

```
@tagname
Scenario: scenarioname
Given some stuff...
```

and run it with 
    `cucumber --tag @tagname`

Comment: Well, that's true, but it's not feasible given that the step i modified is present in 150 out of 1000 existing scenarios. I did some searching and apparently there is no 'beautiful' way of achieving this. So, I am left with only two plausible solutions TAGGING (time consuming) or SCRIPTING (not so elegant).

Comment: Yeah, that's a real pickle (har har)...let me know if you find an elegant solution